# Getting modulo of bytes-number in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

When working in Python, let's say I have a long `bytes` object. I want to get it modulo some number. For example, say I have the bytes object b'hi' and I want it modulo 3, then the result is 26729 % 3 == **2**. (The `bytes` object is seen as one big number.)

How do I do that in Python? (Preferably Python 3.) I'm hoping that there's a relatively elegant way where I don't have to manually compute the number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b'hi', 'big', signed=False) % 3
2
```

Comment: Wonderful! I was worried there wouldn't be an elegant way :)